# Effect of wind on ultrasound sensor

Tags: ultrasound

For example, if I have an ultrasoundsensor 1 m above the ground while there is a wind speed of 5 m/s, a rough estimate of the horizontal displacement of the beam would be

$$ t \approx 2 \frac{1}{343} = 5.831\ \mathrm{ms}$$
$$ d = t \cdot u  = 2.92\ \mathrm{cm}$$

Where $u$ is the wind speed. This would mean my sensor has to decently "spread" its beams so that it can capture one of them. Let alone if $u$ is larger, which might happen in my environment. Are there any decent sources on the effect of wind on the readings of an ultrasound sensor? And how I should compensate for it?

Comment: Seems like you need a stronger beam if a 1m beam deflects 3cm...

Comment: @SolarMike if the medium is moving compared to the emitter, then a stronger beam isn’t going to change the horizontal displacement